# javascript, execute Window open() Method several time in once

Tags: javascript, html

I has been making my own word searching web application.

Here is my partial code

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$('#word').bind("enterKey",function(e){
    var htmlString = $(this).val();
    var res = htmlString.split("\n");
    var wordBox = document.getElementById("word");

    for(var j=0; j<res.length; j++){
        //ignore space 
        if(res[j] == '') 
            continue;

        console.log(res[j]);
        var downloadStr;
        downloadStr = "http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/"+res[j];

        window.open(downloadStr,'_blank');
        $("#unqiue").after('<br>'+'<a href="'+downloadStr+'" target="_blank">'+res[j]+'</a>');
        // $('#'+res[j]).trigger('click');
        wordBox.setSelectionRange(0,htmlString.length); 
    }


});
$('#word').keyup(function(e){
    if(e.keyCode == 13)
    {
        $(this).trigger("enterKey");
    }
});
</script>
```

As you guys can see, if i press the insert the word which what i want to search, and press enter, these script will work.

variable res is a array which contains the words.

So, this script ignore the non-any insertion ('') and add the link to the oxford leaner dictionary containing meaning of the word.

Plus, since i think it is tiresome to click each links for finding meaning, this script also open the new window on same link(var "downloadStr").

However, when i tried to enter button browser only opened one dic-window of first-entered word and over. (Unlike this problem, adding link worked well)

For example, If insert the words/
  flower
  car
  house /
-> and enter -> only flower meaning has appeared.

[image]

I just want to open every window what I entered. (flower, car, house everything only once a time !)

What is the problem with my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like browser pop-up blocker did that

Answer (score 0):

Sorry , I was a just idiot.

Matter of blocking popup of Chrome...